# Matching patterns in List of List in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, pattern-matching

I have a ArrayList of strings LinkSet which contains the following items

```
["0,3","0,13","0,28","12,3","13,3","28,12"]
```

I have another list of list pattern2 with the following containing

```
[[0,3], [0,13,3], [0,28,12,3]]
```

I would like to match each element pattern of the list LinkSet in my list pattern2 and replace the element found by the position of the match from LinkSet. As a result, I would like to have a list of list with like :

```
[[0],[1,4],[2,5,3]]
```

From this new list of list, `0` is the position of the `"0,3"`  from the original list,`1` is the position of `0,13` in the original list and so on.
I tried this:

```
    String pattern2="";
    for (int k=0; k<graph.LinkSet.size();k++)
    {
      String temp=""
      for(int m=0;m<pattern.size();m++)
       {
          temp=pattern.get(m).toString();

        if (temp.contains("[["+LinkSet.get(k)+"],"))
        {
            pattern=pattern+"[["+k+"],";
        }
        else if (temp.contains("["+LinkSet.get(k)+"],"))
        {
            pattern=pattern+"["+k+"],";
        }

        else if (temp.contains(", ["+LinkSet.get(k)))
        {
            pattern=pattern+", ["+k+",";
        }

        else if (temp.contains(", ["+LinkSet.get(k)))
        {
            pattern=pattern+", ["+k+",";
        }
    }
      }
   //System.out.println("after"+temp);
    System.out.println("pattern"+pattern2);
```

But it does not give me what I would like to have. It gives me

```
,[,[[[1,2,3],
```

it seems to overwrite pattern2 for each loop

Comment: _"it does not give me what I would like to have."_ -- well, what does it give you, and what would you like to have? What have you done so far to troubleshoot? Have you stepped through the code in your debugger? Incomplete questions are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is, that you're working on "pattern" and change it inside the innner-loop instead of storing your results in pattern2... But that doesn't explain your results. Also you're messing around with the brackets unnecessarily. And you need to switch the loops to get the result you want.

How about this:

```
String result = "";
// Loop over pattern
for (int m = 0; m < pattern.size(); m++)       {
    String patternResult = "";
    String patternToBeMatched = pattern.get(m);
    // Loop over source
    for (int k=0; k<graph.LinkSet.size(); k++)    {
        String toAnalyse = graph.LinkSet.get(k);
        if (toAnalyse.contains(patternToBeMatched){
            patternResult = patternResult + k + ", ";
        }
    }
    // Remove additional ", " if not empty and set brackets 
    if (patternResult.length() > 0){
        patternResult = "[" + patternResult.substring(0, patternResult.length() - 2) + "]";
    }
    result = result + patternResult;
}
result = "[" + result + "]";
```

Comment: I am not sure why but my result is only []